# Primefaces Chart issue Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateAxisRenderer' of undefined

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jqplot

I'm using primefaces chart in my application. I've placed the chart inside a p:panel and that p:panel in a separate form. and that form is viewed after some navigation is done. Now on clicking a button in the form, I'm rendering the panel containing the chart, where I get the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateAxisRenderer' of undefined
```

but if i put the below line in the page containing the form, the chart is rendered correctly

```
<h:outputScript name="charts/charts.js" library="primefaces" />
```

can anyone tell what goes wrong here ? or do i need to put the h:outputscript tag whereever needed ??

The same happens for lengent position also. legent position were no displayed correctly and was facing some css issues w.r.t to p:chart. but adding the below line in main page, chart is displayed as per expectation

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="charts/charts.css" library="primefaces" />
```

Kindly help.

Comment: you have the `<h:head>..</h:head>` tags on the page?

Comment: @OuerghiYassineya i have <h:head> tag in my master page. But i added the script tag in a different page and still it works